# fragment transaction independent of view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slidingmenu, fragmentstatepageradapter

I want to be able to have a fragment that can only be accessed via a button but also still have a sliding view pager with multiple fragments. I don't want to be able to access this fragment via the slider it has to be independent of it while still being able to access the other fragments with sliding. Is this possible? please I have been stuck on this issue for weeks.

Comment: You want to achieve this only using Fragments? If not there is something called as [AdapterViewFlipper] (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterViewFlipper.html) it may help what your trying to do with out viewpager and fragments.

Comment: I don't think this will help me unfortunately I need to be able to do a fragment transaction and then inside that fragment if they press a tab I need to be able to use the viewpager again.